# How to Augment text data by a group using NLPAUG for group imbalance (Python 3.9.6)

Tags: python, pandas, text, nlp

Good afternoon.

I am running into an issue with NLPAUG Python package. By default the package supports strings or list of strings, but I am interested to see how I can augment data by group. What I am trying to do is create new text records using NLPAUG for underrepresented groups. So if Group E only has one text record, I would like to augment it and create 2 new records or use synonyms for it via NLPAUG package.

I **tried** the following code as recommended by NLPAUG documentation, but it it keeps giving me *AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'strip'* error message

**Code Tried**

```
aug_wordnet = naw.SynonymAug(aug_src='wordnet',aug_max=3)

aug_data = []
for group, d in mydataframe.groupby(['Group']):
  a_data = aug_wordnet.augment(d)
  a_data = pd.DataFrame(aug_data, columns=['Comment'])
  a_data['Group'] = Group
  aug_data.append(a_data)

aug_data = pd.concat(aug_data)
```

Here is what my data looks like.

**Input Example**

| ID | Comment | Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | This is good | A |
| 34 | This is OK | A |
| 56 | This is excellent | A |
| 78 | This is awful | A |
| 91 | This is good | B |
| 11 | This is awful | B |
| 21 | This is awful | C |
| 22 | This is awful | C |
| 23 | This is Amazing | C |
| 24 | This is Wonderful | D |

**Output Example** - using Synonyms from NLPAUG for group D

| ID | Comment | Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | This is good | A |
| 34 | This is OK | A |
| 56 | This is excellent | A |
| 78 | This is awful | A |
| 91 | This is good | B |
| 11 | This is awful | B |
| 21 | This is awful | C |
| 22 | This is awful | C |
| 23 | This is Amazing | C |
| 24 | This is **replaced with synonym** for Wonderful | D |
| 24 | This is Great | D |
| 24 | This is Excellent | D |

How can I tackle this issue?

Thank you

Comment: I came up with a solution. I will post it here once I clean up the code to it helps anyone else looking into a similar issue